# Linking email column from one table to username column of another table using Java with Spring & JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc

I am using Spring Boot with Spring Data JPA. I have two tables named User and Employee.

Employee.java

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Employee implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3732596549369515261L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;    
    
    private String name;
    private String designation;
    private Date dateOfJoining;
    private String workLocation;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private Long contactNo;
    
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;
    private Date dateOfLeaving;   
}
```

User.java

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User 
{
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    
    private String username;
    private String password;    
}
```

I want to create a relation between Employee.email with User.username. Will this be possible via any JPA annotations.

I tried with Mappings from JPA and none of them is working as the User.username is String, unlike Employee object.

Comment: What type of relation? Also share what you've tried thus far.

Comment: The username value of the User table must be a record of the Employee table email Column.
Tried JoinColumn with OneToOne mapping but the type we need to mention is Object reference only(Employee) unlike String I am actually looking for.

Comment: anyone get an answer for this?